# How to dynamically name structure elements?

Tags: coldfusion

```
xls.each(function(v, k) {
    oid = v.OrderID;        
    xlsindexed[oid] = v;//This gives me a struct with 9999 empty values.
});
```

I'm trying to get an array/structure with each element named as the orderID, and the value of each to be the struct with the order details.

I've tried all kinds of combinations of

```
xlsindexed[oid] = v;
xlsindexed.oid = v;
xlsindexed.#oid# = v;
```

etc

also, tried:

```
xlsindexed[oid] = 'blah';
```

and still get struct with 9999 [undefined array element]s
My xls variable has about 30 elements.

Comment: sounds like your problem is with what `v` is, not the way you're assigning to the struct. ( `struct[var]` is the correct way )

Comment: Looked into that, also.  See edit.

Comment: Again, i don't think `v` is what you think it is. Whatever it is, it doesn't appear to have an OrderID property. Isn't it just a key?

Comment: I *think* it's the value of the current element, in each(), and I *think* k is the key for that element.  I dump oid, and get all my orderID's, as expected.  BUt, even when i dont use v, i get this huge 9999 struct.

Comment: I know in lucee `.each` on a struct, the callback receives the key as the first arg. To get the value you would have to do `struct[key]`. Not entirely sure what it is in ACF, wasn't able to find it in docs.

Comment: a simple `writeDump(arguments); abort;` would clear this up quickly

Comment: xlsindexed['_'&v.OrderID] = v; Works.  Adds the underscore, but it works.

Comment: cf cant take a number, as a struct key???

Comment: hmm... never looked into it, always assumed it would need a string. Also figured it would coerce it to a string automagically, guess not. lucee seems to make it a string just fine

Comment: *RE: This gives me a struct with 9999 empty values* Technically you get an *array* with that many undefined elements. The reason is that when `xlsindexed` is undefined, CF has to guess what type of object `xlsindexed[someNumericValue] = v;` should produce: an array or structure. Apparently, it sees the numeric value and guesses you want an array.  If you declare `xlsindexed` as a structure beforehand, ie `xlsindexed = {}`, it removes the ambiguity and produces the expected result.

Comment: Thank you, Leigh, this solves it.

Comment: Cool. I will write up an answer, in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comments...)

> This gives me a struct with 9999 empty values

Technically you get an *array* with that many undefined elements. The reason that happens is that when `xlsindexed` is undefined, CF has to guess what type of object this:

```
  xlsindexed[ someNumericValue ] = v;
```

.. should produce: an array or a structure. Apparently, it sees the numeric value and guesses you want an array. So it creates and initializes an array with that many elements.

If you declare `xlsindexed` as a structure beforehand, it removes the ambiguity and produces the expected result.

```
// initialize as a structure
xlsindexed = {};
xls.each(function(v, k) {
    xlsindexed[v.OrderID] = v;
});
```